# Bash Commands from C# / some work some dont

Tags: linux

I'm very new to Linux, so I don't understand why commands like `whoami` work well, but something like `sudo raspi-config nonint get_i2c` yields a 127 error (command not found)

Formal documentation for raspi-config noint command arguments:
([formal nonint documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/develop/documentation/asciidoc/computers/configuration/raspi-config.adoc#raspi-config-cli))

Using the awesome Bash extension as blogged here:
https://jackma.com/2019/04/20/execute-a-bash-script-via-c-net-core/#comment-1576

I should also say that I'm running a Docker Image inside of IOT Edge to get access to the OS commands. I can easily SSH to the device, but into the same environment that Docker Image is running. I don't understand why one bash command would work, while the other does not.

after this command, which I got from an SSH to the device ... `sh -x /usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c`

```
 + INTERACTIVE=True
 + ASK_TO_REBOOT=0
 + BLACKLIST=/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
 + CONFIG=/boot/config.txt
 + USER=UserXXX001
 + ps --no-headers -o comm 1
 + INIT=systemd
 + is_pi
 + dpkg --print-architecture
 + ARCH=arm64
 + [ arm64 = armhf ]
 + [ arm64 = arm64 ]
 + return 0
 + [ -e /proc/device-tree/chosen/os_prefix ]
 + cat /proc/device-tree/chosen/os_prefix
 + PREFIX=
 + CMDLINE=/boot/cmdline.txt
 + INTERACTIVE=False
 + nonint get_i2c
 + get_i2c
 + grep -q -E ^(device_tree_param|dtparam)=([^,]*,)*i2c(_arm)?(=(on|true|yes|1))?(,.*)?$ /boot/config.txt
 + echo 0
0
 + exit 0
```

output from "env" (when I ssh into the device)

```
root@NewDeviceConfiguration:/home/XXXUserId# env
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_GID=1000
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
SUDO_USER=XXXUserId
NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
PWD=/home/XXXUserId
LOGNAME=root
HOME=/root
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
TERM=xterm-256color
USER=root
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SUDO_UID=1000
MAIL=/var/mail/root
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I also echo the $PATH statement, using the same code I'm using in my attempt to execute raspi_conifg

> environment path variable:>/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

So I did an /usr/bin/ls -l using the code I use to invoke a command... and I'm not seeing the "raspi-config" statement!

[image]

Why not? the image I'm using to create docker is: 7.0-bullseye-slim-arm64v8 which understandably does NOT have raspi-config as a script file... but the script file exists on the host disk, which I can see. Both have the "/usr/bin" directory, but they are different.  I understand the security aspects of why this is not a good idea, but there is no way GPIO can live inside the image, so why are the scripts on the host not accessible?

Comment: And that IOT Edge thing lives on a raspberry pi?

Comment: Yes, but I'm able to do various commands, just not raspi-config

Answer (score 1):

If some command is not in PATH (see `echo $PATH` in shell prompt), there will be "command not found" printed by shell. Directories in $PATH search path are examined to find an executable.
If the `raspi-config` is among directories from $PATH, the next point to checkout could be one of programs called from `raspi-config` (raspi-config is a  shell script itself). To check out if some programs are missing (or not in $PATH), run raspi-config script in debug mode (with arguments from your example as `sh -x /usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c`, or with other full path to raspi-config if it's located somewhere else)

p.s. cannot put it into comments above, sorry, so it's written as an answer

Comment: Interesting, I updated the question with the command you provided... the way this gets executed is /bin/bash -f "command goes here", so perhaps the path is different when the process starts?

Comment: running `sh -x /usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c` it shows '0' in output and how it got it, i.e. i2c bus is enabled in config.txt, so it works. Try to run `sudo /usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c` or just `/usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c`, if it will say "/usr/bin/raspi-config is not found", so there is no  /usr/bin/raspi-config script there in that environment or system. It's how I understand it.

Comment: Another option: if that subsystem doesn't interpret properly shebang (#!/bin/sh) in the first line of raspi-config script, try to use  `bash -c '/usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c'` as a command (i.e. bash -c 'script itsargs' in place of 'script itsargs')

Comment: note, you've tried to run `bash -c './usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c'`, not `bash -c '/usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c'`.<br>I.e. trim the leading `.` dot before `/usr/bin/raspi-config`

Comment: I removed the error, as well as updated the question...very strange why this happening!  continuing to pursue!

Comment: Oh crap - new to Docker and Linux is not a good thing - I was assuming that a Linux command on the device (like when I SSH into the device), would be the same inside the docker image?  The device has the OS that Raspberry PI imager has, the Docker image is derived from "7.0-bullseye-slim-arm64v8".  How do I know the capabilities of the image in terms Linux commands?

Comment: for getting information about distro/kernel/arch, there are two commands (first one is common for all unixes, the second is for debian-derived distros):
(1) `uname -a`
(2) `lsb_release -a`

Comment: suggestion: test out if shebang is interpreted correctly by subsystem which net/core uses, i.e. call .cs shell_helper for the next two commands:
(1) `sudo raspi-config nonint get_i2c`
(2) `sudo bash -c "raspi-config nonint get_i2c"`

Comment: This has me very perplexed and wanting to understand what is happening and why.  Will issue more commands as you suggested

Comment: step by step to find a failure point.  Starting with testing sudo, if it works and there's that raspi-config script in system, i.e. `sudo ls -l /usr/bin/raspi-config`. If it's okay and works then `sudo /usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c`, if it still doesn't work, then `sudo bash -c "/usr/bin/raspi-config nonint get_i2c"`. There's nothing unusual particulary with linux or shell. Question is about what that net/core script can do and what cannot do. It's as I see it.

Comment: See screen shot above: the image I'm using to create docker is: 7.0-bullseye-slim-arm64v8 which understandably does NOT have raspi-config as a script file... but the script file exists on the host disk, which I can see. Both have the "/usr/bin" directory, but they are different.  I understand the security aspects of why this is not a good idea, but there is no way GPIO can live inside the image, so why are the scripts on the host not accessible?

Comment: sorry, I'm not very familiar with rpi docker images, maybe it's a good separate question how to map i2c bus into or from a docker image